# Is there any way to use TypeFace directly by passing URL?

Tags: android, api, fonts

I am trying to use font directly from api. This is an api of font ABeeZee 
http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v11/kpplLynmYgP0YtlJA3atRw.ttf

Normally if my font is stored in assets/fonts folder i could use

```
TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ABeZee.ttf");
    heading.setTypeface(typeFace);
    heading.setText(headerInfo.getName().trim());
```

but i want to use it directly passing api. Is there any way?

Comment: You want to change font for all whole application?

Comment: Do you want to download font and then use it ? Or you want to use pre-built asset fonts .Make it clear .

Comment: Downloading it in a temporary file would help. Thank you in advance... @ADM

Comment: you want to use custom text view.

Comment: actually i have a listview and for each row in listView i want to use different fonts from google api. @MuhammadSaad

Comment: Setting fonts from the cloud on loading is not a good practice. You can pre- download all fonts and save them external storage  and the set the typeface.

Comment: To expand on @ADM  setting fonts from the cloud is a bad idea because the file locations could change or the file could be deleted.  Bundle it with your app instead.

Comment: well then i guess pre downloading is the only better way. @ADM thank you for your help

Comment: thank you everyone for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are pre-downloading the fonts. So save them in app cache directory

```
getFilesDir()- To get your own files dir , your package name and "/files" need to be appended to it.
```

In that way you fonts will be secure(Less chances that user will manually delete them). Check for file before creating typeface.

```
private Typeface getFont(String filePath){
    File file=new File(filePath);
    if(file.exists()) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile("filePath");
        return typeface;
    }
    return null;
}
```